# How to get the row where it's value has a continuous decrease compared to the last two rows in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame create by pandas like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['q1','q2','q3','q4','q5'],'vlue':[17,20,16,13,17]})

   name vlue
0   q1  17
1   q2  20
2   q3  16
3   q4  13
4   q5  17
```

I want the row that has a continuous decrease compared to the last two rows.

In this case, the value of `q4` is 13, it's decreased compared to `q3`'s value 16 and `q2`'s  value 20.
so the answer should be q4.

what's an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
df.loc[(df.vlue<df.vlue.shift(1))&(df.vlue.shift(1)<df.vlue.‌​shift(2)), 'name']
#3    q4
#Name: name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2):

In two lines :

```
In [19]: dicrease = df.vlue.diff() < 0

In [20]: df.name[dicrease & dicrease.shift()]
Out[20]: 
3    q4
Name: name, dtype: object
```